# Iam unable to define how to map two foreign key columns of two different table in Entity class of other table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Iam unable to define how to map two foreign key columns of two different table in Entity class of other table.

let me give example of table structure

```
table1
   column11 (primary key)
   column12 
   column13

table2
   column21 (primary key)
   column11 (foreign key - table1 primary key column)
   column22
   column23

table3
   column31 (primary key)
   column11 (foreign key - table1 primary key column)
   column21 (foreign key - table2 primary key column)
   column32
   column33
```

Now i want to my entity class table3 to hold these two foreign keys. Iam very new to JPA(hibernate) . How can i map those foreign key columns as entity class attributes?
Please suggest me.

Comment: Get rid of column11 (foreign key - table1 primary key column) from table3, because by column21 (foreign key - table2 primary key column) you should be able to access info from table1, if my thought is in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Entity
public class Table3 {
    // ...

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "column11")
    private Table1 table1;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "column21")
    private Table2 table2;

    // ...
}
```

Comment: iam getting nullpointer exception, when inserting data, getting stacktrace as column11 cannt be Null, even thought iam setting value to table1 object like, Table1 table1 = new Table1(); table1.setColumn11(<value>); table3.setTable1(table1);

Comment: Then ask another question, with the code and mapping of the two entities, the code used to create and persist them, and the stack trace of the exception.

Comment: i edited the answer which worked for me well. Iam able to persist data.